# how does host differentiate MVC request and Web API request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to asp.net mvc and web api. I'm reading a book which says:

ASP.NET MVC uses: `System.Web.HttpRequest`

and Web API Equivalent is `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`

and below is a picture that describes the request and result flow of web api

[image]

So my question is, how does hosting environment(which will typically be IIS) know that it should create a HttpRequestMessage object to represent the request from the client? I mean if the application is a MVC application, IIS should create a HttpRequest object instead of HttpRequestMessage, so how does IIS know which one to create?

Comment: At a high level, you can just have a managed code handler in IIS. that would then load either WebAPI or MVC framework library, which would convert base IIS classes to the appropriate framework wrappers. The change in WebAPI was done to make the code more unit testable coz everything pretty much became abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the picture you posted, the `HttpRequestMessage` exists only inside the "hosting" environment, web browser client does not know anything about that.

In the "hosting" world, IIS app pool is running the code you have built and deployed which knows very well wich framewok you are using as your code also contains the using assemblies you listed, System.Web... or System.Net...

Consider that even if you have shown separation between hosting, Controller and Action, all of that is running in same App Pool in IIS which, again, runs your code so knows what it is about as your IL assemblies were built from your specific source code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I never have experence in IIS, so just to confirm again,: it is IIS's job to create different object, if the deployed appilcation is MVC app, then IIS creates `HttpRequest` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question but this might be what you're looking for:

> I mean if the application is a MVC application, IIS should create a
>   HttpRequest object instead of HttpRequestMessage, so how does IIS know
>   which one to create?

You must remember how you differentiate between a normal MVC Controller and a Web API Controller...

WebAPI Controllers enforces this annotation `[ApiController]` and must inherits from `ControllerBase`:

`[ApiController]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase {
   //Your API methods here
}`

A normal MVC Controller only inherits from `Controller` base class:

`public class PeopleController : Controller {
   //Your Action methods here...
}`

Those already create configuration for your APP which becomes easier for you Hosting environment to know what is going and what to return when.

I hope you find this helpful.